# Extra content at the end of document - XML PArsing Error

Tags: xml

I wrote this bit of XML as my first try, but somehow it gives an error.  I have already read the other post on the topic which tell you to have 1 root parent; in my case this would be Catalog. And I also gave the attributes a single name without white spaces. Any idea's what the problem could be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Catalog>
  <EnginePart1>
    <petrolType>Diesel</petrolType>                                         
    <GeneralInfo>   
        <CarBrand>ALFA ROMEO</CarBrand> 
        <NoOfCyl>4</NoOfCyl>
        <BoreDia>69.6mm</BoreDia>
        <Capacity>1,248cc</Capacity>
    </GeneralInfo> 
    <Image>
            <file type="PNG">Capture.PNG3.PNG</file>
    </Image>
    <LinerKit>                                          
        <ReferenceNo /> 
    </LinerKit> 
    <PistonRings>                                       
        <Name>PKAR406963DB</Name>
        <ReferenceNumber>
            <Name1>K-40659600</Name1>
            <Name2>N-8742560000</Name2>
        </ReferenceNumber>
    </PistonRings> 
    <PistonSet>                                         
        <Name>PTAR406963DB</Name>
        <ReferenceNo />
            <Description>
                <Name1>alfin and with oil gallery</Name1>
                <Name2>skirt MOS2 treated fits tapered con. rod</Name2>
            </Description>
            <Piston>
                <Length>62.5</Length>
                <Comp>40.5</Comp>
                <Height1>-6</Height1>
                <Height2>-12.3</Height2>
            </Piston>
            <Pin>
                <Diameter>23.0</Diameter>
                <Length>57.0</Length>
            </Pin>
    </PistonSet> 
    <RingsSet>
        <Name>PRAR406961D</Name>
        <ReferenceNo>
            <Name1>A-R66830</Name1>
            <Name2>G-0813760000</Name2>
            <Name3>K-800056240000</Name3>
            <Name4>M-01004N0</Name4>
        </ReferenceNo>
        <Description />
        <Rings>
            <Top>2.0</Top>
            <2nd>1.5</2nd>
            <Oil>2.0</Oil>
        </Rings>
    </RingsSet>
    <CylLiner>
        <Name></Name>
        <ReferenceNo />
        <Description />
        <LinerSleeve>
            <Lenght />
            <OutsideDiameter />
            <FlangeDiameter /> 
            <FlangeDepth />
        </LinerSleeve>
    </CylLiner>
  </EnginePart1>
</Catalog>
```

Comment: What my answer helpful for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you so much for the help. I'll be sure to think of this the next time I'm working in xml :)

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is with the `<2nd>` tag on line 54.  Tag names cannot start with a number.

Here's a handy tool for identifying the source of problems in XML: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

For future reference, XML elements must follow these naming rules:

- Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
- Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
- Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- Names cannot contain spaces